# Loop command only consist of last value

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, read.csv

I am trying to read.csv a series of file named ("year".csv) from year 2005 to 2007 and writing into database.

However the loop command only consist of "2007L" for element "i" and only read 2007.csv into the dataframe.

Any ideas on how to resolve the issue ?

```
   for(i in c(2005:2007)){
    ontime<-read.csv(paste0(i,".csv"), header=TRUE)}
    if(i == 2005){  
        dbWriteTable(conn,"ontimet",ontimet)
       } else {
       dbWriteTable(conn,"ontimet",ontimet, append= TRUE)
       }
   }
```

Comment: You should include the package that `dbWriteTable` is in. Also, while it makes sense that the loop ends with `ontime` being 2007, the real question is whether your database is updated as you want. However, if you want a data.frame with all the years,  you can do something like `data.table::rbindlist(lapply(paste0(2005:2007, ".csv"), data.table::fread))`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be what you need. I think you just need to assign variables and append in the right place.

You probably need is like this. It produces all three years (or in your case, it would be csv's)

```
tmp = NULL

for(i in c(2005:2007)){
    if(i == 2005){  
        tmp = append(tmp, i)
    } else {
        tmp = append(tmp, i)
        print(tmp)
    }
}
```